# Matrix multiplication using tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run this code for linear regression using Tensor Flow. I have to use Tensor Flow matrix multiplication, but I am getting errors.

My code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
tf.set_random_seed(777)  
tf.reset_default_graph()

x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_train = [1.1,2.3, 3.2,4.0,5.4]


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='bias')


#hypothesis = tf.linalg.matmul(X,W)+ b
hypothesis = tf.matmul(X,W) + b`
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with multplication? Have you tried to add using tensorflow?
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/add

Comment: yes, I was getting this error: "Shape must be at least rank 2 but is rank 1 for '{{node MatMul}} = BatchMatMulV2[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false](Placeholder, weight/read)' with input shapes: ?, [1]."

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this problem is here:

```
 W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='weight')
```

This is returning one random scalar value. It should be a matrix taking the form:

```
 W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n,m]), name='weight')
```

Here n and m are integers. It works even if they are both equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

`tf. matmul` is a matrix multiplication, at least one of the args must have a shape of size 2. In your case, this code should work:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,5]), name='weight')
```

5 because of the size of x_train. Though it would also be possible to get something like:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n,5]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n]), name='bias')
```

instead. As the result of the multiplication will be added to b, the output size must be compatible with the size of b.